# React native, flex and width parent element

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

With react native and flex, I write this:

```
<View style={[styles.cell_content]}>
    <Text style={[styles.title]}>
        Sexualité et prévention
    </Text>
    ...


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cell_content: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    title: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 2.5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        padding: 5,
    },
})
```

This is result :

[image]

But I want the yellow background to be adapted to the text, not 100%.
If I create container for title ( `<View style={styles.title_container}><Text style={[styles.title]}>...</Text></View>` ) this is same result ...

Comment: Try `display: 'inline-block'` on title

Comment: I think Inline-block is not autorised in react native : https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet

Comment: then try flex with a width setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I want the yellow background to be adapted to the text, not 100%

You can wrap your `Text` element with a `View`, and then put a dummy `Text` element next to your `Text` to cover the remaining empty space.

Like so:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.yourText}>
      Sexualité et prévention
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.textDummy}/>
</View>
```

CSS:

```
  container: {
   flexDirection:"row",
  },
  yourText: {
    backgroundColor:"yellow"
  },
  textDummy: {
    flexGrow:1
  }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

---

As a second solution you can add just

```
 alignSelf: "baseline"
```

to your `title`. Like this:

```
 title: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 2.5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        padding: 5,
        alignSelf:"baseline"
    }
```

Comment: Mmmm ... it's the best solution you think? A lot of code ... :/

Comment: Updated my answer, check it out. @Gaylord.P

Comment: Thanks very much for the second solution :)